# Prime integer factorization of $n!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

In the prime integer factorization of $n!$, if $p$ is a prime number and $p$ is a number in this factorization, it's exponent is in the form:  $\alpha =\lfloor \frac{n}{p}\rfloor +\lfloor \frac{n}{p^2}\rfloor  +\lfloor \frac{n}{p^3}\rfloor +\ldots $.
My thoughts were:
$n!=n(n-1)\ldots 3\cdot 2 $
$n=\sum_{i=1}^\infty p_i ^{\alpha_{n_i}}, (n-1)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty p_i ^{\alpha_{(n-1)_i}}, \ldots \Rightarrow n!=\sum_{i=1}^\infty p_i ^{\alpha_{2_i}+\alpha_{2_i}+\alpha_{3_i}+\ldots+\alpha_{n_i}}$

Therefore I now "only" have to show that   $\alpha_j=\lfloor \frac{n}{p_j}\rfloor +\lfloor \frac{n}{p_j^2}\rfloor  +\lfloor \frac{n}{p_j^3}\rfloor +\ldots =\alpha_{2_j}+\alpha_{2_j}+\alpha_{3_j}+\ldots+\alpha_{n_j}$

My thoughts on that were to show it by proving that the inequalities in both directions do not apply, and therefore equality must be truth, but I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question regarding to canonical factorization of $n!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22637/question-regarding-to-canonical-factorization-of-n)

Comment: I gave a proof by induction http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n/228351#228351

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\lfloor n/p \rfloor$ is the number of multiples of $p$ from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: Okay, now it is clear to me why the equality must hold, but I don't know how to write it formally, since some $ \alpha_{i_j}=0 $